# Test the combined hypothesis "X is correlated with Y and is uncorrelated with Z"

Tags: correlation, p-value

If I have 3 variables, $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, what statistical approach might I use to ask the question "is in population X correlated with $Y$ but is uncorrelated with $Z$"?

Obviously, I can assess if $X$ is correlated with $Y$ and separately if $X$ is correlated with $Z$ and have two p-values:

```
p1 <- cor.test(X,Y)$p.value
p2 <- cor.test(X,Z)$p.value
```

But I'm not sure how I'd go about sort of "combining" these two results **into one p-value** of my combined hypothesis. Or maybe there is a totally different approach for this question?

Comment: It's great that you have a substantially less vague hypothesis going into this than usual but it leaves some questions open.  What alternatives do you want this tested against and what is "uncorrelated"?  Do you want it tested against both being uncorrelated, both being correlated, the inverse finding of correlation, all of those?  And how low a correlation is "uncorrelated"?  Does it have to be exaclty 0?  What's the range of values you'll consider uncorrelated?  Does the sign of the correlation matter?

Comment: @ScanSally I've edited your question, please inspect now.

Comment: I think what I am interested is if X is correlated with Y and not correlated with Z, irrespective of direction, i.e. X can be correlated with Y in either direction, but must not be correlated with Z in either direction. I can't really say exactly how low a correlation I want to define as "uncorrelated", but close to zero I guess. I think this problem may be a little more difficult than I'd anticipated!

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this so?